# does it good & safe enough? to estabish additional connection for particular page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have aleady use mysqli for the main connection, but use this mysql for additioal connection on particular page.

```
class DBController {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $password = "";
private $database = "blog_samples";

function __construct() {
    $conn = $this->connectDB();
    if(!empty($conn)) {
        $this->selectDB($conn);
    }
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
    return $conn;
}
```

Is it good & safe enough? Are there better way for doing this? please explain me the advantage. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is already bad because `mysql` api is deprecated in latest php5 and removed in php7. And you __must__ forget about it and use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: As already said, stop using mysql and use mysqli or PDO instead. Also, you should check if the connection was successfull or not, and return some errors. Use try / catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdo method for connection and check.

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Other method also are `mysql` or `mysqli` as per your php version.

```
// Try and connect to the database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username,$password,$dbname);

// If connection was not successful, handle the error
if($connection === false) {
    // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but I have already used mysqli for my main connection. And the mysql I use for seconds connection on particular page only. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes you can use private connection for particular page and query but you should check your php version and query which connection you passed in your query. you have all types of flexibility.

Comment: Never echo PHP errors right away

Comment: It still working good on PHP 5.6.